# Best Practice of multi language Android App

Tags: android, string, kotlin, android-resources

I'm making an android app with multi-language support. 
I have around 30 language to support my app.

**I'm playing within 2 Case.**

case 1 .   First case is creating values folder of every language in res                   folder.

case 2.    Second case Get every language content with a key from server

```
     e.g. TXT_HELLO  = HELLO if user choose English
          TXT_HELLO. = HOLA. if user choose Spanish

  Suppose from language list I select Spanish during language change 
  then server give me list of every Spanish content with a same key 

         [Key]    = [Value]
 e.g.  TXT_HELLO  =  Hola
       TXT_GOOD   =  Bueno 

  & then I save this value with key is session & all key also in my Constant class 
Similarly In Case if I select English:
           [Key]    = [Value]
     e.g.  TXT_HELLO  =  Hello
           TXT_GOOD   =  good.   as Soon
```

**This is how my kotlin code work.**

```
fun getLanguageValue(key : String)->{

return  sharedPre.getString(key)

}

txtViewHello.text =  getLanguageValue(MyConstant.TXT_HELLO)
```

**cons and pros of case 1 .**

pros : It handle by system and good memory management

cons : Language only can add on new release apk. if some word is wrong then can't be correct without release.

**cons and pros of case 2** .

pros :   if some word is wrong then can correct online. No need to release new APK or can add more language at any time.

cons : It handle by me and initialization of objects is more complex.

So please suggest me what is best approach & what is best practice to change language.

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt to write your own language switcher that does this, but I'd advise against it. This is basically fighting the system, and is very hard to handle properly.

The best way to handle multiple languages is to use resource qualifiers, and make the system do the hard work for you. It will also match the user's expectation that your app will be in the same language as the entire rest of their phone.

Comment: how I write I own language switcher ?

Comment: Basically, you don't.

Comment: So what you suggest me finally.

Comment: You should use the recommended method of resource files with language qualifiers